# should I create a VM and then use docker machine inside the VM for development

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, containers, virtualbox, centos7

In order to address the issue of different developers using different OSs (Windows, OS X, and Linux), does it make sense to create a customized VirtualBox Image and install Docker Machine (which I know creates another VM) within the customized VM?

I do know the purpose of Docker Machine is to facilitate the development both at local and production environment. More importantly, It creates a VM. Therefore, installing Docker Machine inside another VM does not seems to make much of sense.

However, in order to guarantee all developers are actually experiencing the exact same local environment. It seems to make sense to have a customized VM (with vagrant) to automate the entire process of installing everything including Docker Machine.

So, please let me know what is a best practice?

1. Vagrant a CentOS machine, and automate the process of installing Docker Machine. Using the Docker machine to create Docker Containers.
2. Let developers to install their own Docker Machine. Using the Docker machine to create Docker Containers.
3. Vagrant a CentOS machine and install Docker Engine rather than install Docker Machine. Use Docker Engine to create Docker Containers.

Comment: Docker Machine is for Windows and OS X. For CentOS VM, you should (and you can only) use Docker Engine directly. I think number 3 is probably the best route if you want everyone to have exactly the same environment.

Comment: Approach 1 does not make sense, 2 and 3 are valid options. See my comment below as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that "installing docker-machine" is actually just downloading one file from [docker-machine releases](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases). No need for Vagrant.

`docker-machine` in a Linux/CentOS environment would only make sense if you need to deploy containers to remote cloud environments (AWS, Azure, ...) from that server. As commented, Vagrant would help only for installing docker itseld.

Comment: I think the main point in the original question is that some developers are only using Linux as their host / usual development OS, while others are on Windows and Mac. CentOS would just be the choice to make it common for all. Otherwise some devs need docker machine, while others don't. You are right though, docker-machine on CentOS would not make much sense (http://bit.ly/1OU7iej) as the OP described in approach (1), but running docker directly within a CentOS makes all users NOT use docker machine. I think that was the actual idea of the OP (as described in approach (3) rather than (1)).

Comment: @MathiasConradt good point. I'll wait for the OP's feedback to know more about the specifics of this question.

Comment: Thanks, vonC and @Mathias. Indeed, the purpose is that developers on different OSs can have the exact same experience. 
More specifically, I want all developers to just run
`vagrant up --provision`, and they are ready to write code without worrying about which environment they are in.
In addition, I do eventually want to deploy the code to remote cloud environments.